# Why does Debian under-report the space available when installing Qt?

Tags: software-installation, disk-usage, qt

I want to install Qt on my Debian but it doesn't detect the whole free space! I tried to install it in /home/Qt but it says that only 23.87 MiB of space is available while `df -h` says that there is still 7.2G free.

[image]

Comment: What does it say if you click the "Show Details" button in that dialog?

Comment: It just lists the components and dependencies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root file system (which by the way is extremely small, even considering that you have /home, /tmp, /usr and /var elsewhere) is practically full; that exact `df` invocation reports 24 MB free on /, which adds up well with the 23.87 MiB reported by the wizard.

I'm guessing this is because parts need to go into locations outside of the supposed installation directory. Though nearly 1 GB seems rather excessive.

What you have for / would really be a more appropriate size for a separate /boot or similar.

Comment: So I should extend the size of / ?

Comment: Well, the reported free space matches that of your root file system very closely, so that's where I would start if possible. Give yourself some headroom if you can; for comparison, my / is 100G and I'm using 13G currently for a workstation system.

Comment: Okay, and how can I resize / then? I added 20 Go to the virtual machine.

Comment: That depends on how it was set up, and is a separate question. (I'm pretty sure that sort of questions have already been asked on numerous occasions, so make sure to search before you) create a new question specifically about that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'd guess it wants to use space in `/opt`

Comment: @user2429940 Also, if this is a new VM you just set up, it might be easier to just blow it away and partition correctly from the start. I suggest picking 'use one partition and set up LVM' in d-i.

Comment: Exactly, I want to extend /opt. I thought of using GParted to do so. I should I maby just blow the current VM and create a brand new one?

Comment: *If* /opt is the culprit, you can simply create a new partition in the newly added space and mount it on /opt. However, I still think your root file system is seriously undersized. It *can* be fixed, but if you haven't done anything you care about in that VM, it's probably easier to just reinstall the VM from scratch with a sane partitioning scheme e.g. as suggested by @derobert.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, just blow away the current VM and create a new one. thanks for advice.

Comment: @user2429940 Glad to be able to help. If you feel this answer addresses your question as asked, please indicate so by upvoting and accepting. Thank you!